# Flutter Error : Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

The application which I am working on is debugging fine in emulator or in mobiles but when I try to build the apk it gives the following Error:

```
Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/cicada/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar.
         > Failed to transform '/home/cicada/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           20.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of image picker?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**This was my solution which I recommend to be the 2nd option:**

**Solution 1:**
I added following lines in the **android directory of app level build.gradle *i.e android/app/build.gradle*** of my  project.

```
   lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable "Instantiatable"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

And every thing started to work fine.
[Check out my Gradle File](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learning-firebase-2d636.appspot.com/o/build.gradle?alt=media&token=801bbb4a-6560-45f7-88de-7d9b594f3dfe)

**Solution 2:**

However I suggest you people by the solution of @Vinadon and agree with the comment of @raiderOne:
1st recommended solution should be:

The issues lies in image_picker_android being updated to gradle 7.1.2. See their changelog. Following an issue on GitHub you have to update your gradle version like so:

In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties update your distributionUrl to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

and in android/build.gradle change the gradle version to at least 7.1.2

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2
```

In @Vinadon case, He had to update his Android Studio for a newer Java version too.
***Upvote Vindadon answer below for this solution.*** Thanks!

Comment: I feel like this is avoiding the problem and not solving it...

Answer (score 46):

The issues lies in `image_picker_android` being updated to gradle 7.1.2. See their [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_android/changelog). Following an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105573) you have to update your gradle version like so:

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` update your distributionUrl to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

and in `android/build.gradle` change the gradle version to at least `7.1.2`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2
```

In my case, I had to update my Android Studio for a newer Java version too.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Upvote it. The rest is workarounds and bandaids.

Comment: doing this made some other plugins not work sadly, so I had to use the dependency_overrides method instead.

Comment: that is the one which works with me

Answer (score 27):

**Let me help you a little bit in finding the correct place to paste the code**

1: Go to your app-level build.grade.

[image]

2:Scroll down to "android{ "
paste this code carefully(not disturbing any other brakets.)

```
lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
            disable "Instantiatable"
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
```

[image]

3:run "flutter clean"
4:run "flutter pub get"
5:If you want to build apk of your project then run "flutter build apk"

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 18):

The solution is actual on 06.06.2022. Adding these lines in pubspec.yaml fixed the problem:

```
dependency_overrides:
  image_picker_android: 0.8.4+13
```

Comment: I did these but it didnot work for me

Comment: so what's the reason or explanation for the problem?

Answer (score 5):

if you are using flutter 3.0 and image_picker, try this:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  image_picker_android: 0.8.4+13
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually because the gradle plugin is outdated. If your project was created using an older version of flutter the gradle plugin will be old. The actual fix to this issue would be to upgrade the gradle plugin version.

Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105573)

You can use android studio to do this for you  or just edit the files on your own.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flutter 3.3 and image_picker, try this:

```
  dependency_overrides:
  image_picker_android: 0.8.5+3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed that by adding the line `android.jetifier.blacklist=org.robolectric.*,bcprov` in gradle.properties

This is the error message I got,
[image]